# Real-time streaming from Android camera to browser

Tags: javascript, android, video-streaming, real-time, ip-camera

We are working on an IP camera Android app that should stream the video took in real-time by the Android camera to a Web page served by the same app and accessed through WiFi only.

The app currently use a pseudo-streaming method (an image sent using HTTP with no-store), but it is not robust enough, so we need to change it for a better streaming method. We also need to support multicast (or at least an optimized "multi-unicast"), and if possible use an UDP protocol (or at least a low-latency TCP protocol).

We cannot use any intermediary server (so no Wowza or the like, unless it is also served by the app) or any browser plugin (so no VLC or the like, unless it is served by the app too). The main browser it is used on is Chromium.

We searched for and tried a lot of methods but none worked for us :

- WebRTC sounds cool, but it uses an intermediary signaling server, it doesn't support multicast, and it is kind of heavy for what we want
- RTSP with libstreaming sounds cool too, but no browser seems to implement it, and we couldn't find a Javascript library to do it.
- RTMP works on most browsers, but we could'nt find a working Android library

**Which streaming method would be best for our needs, and do you know Javascript and Android libraries implementing them ?**

Comment: on android , can you use a webView in order to capture user media?  If the session access to the android device cam is via get usermedia in a page w JS,  then you may be able to use an entire webRTC example to peer the media object from the camera . "stream from video to peer"  ... https://webrtc.github.io/samples/

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to stream multicast to a browser.